# Podman build fails with exit status 137 while building Rust code

Tags: rust, containers, podman

I am using podman to containerize [this](https://github.com/JoaoPedroPP/barIO-ubackend) rust code on a `darwin/arm64` system for `linux/amd64` platform, however I am getting 137 error status on the building process.

I am using the ContainerFile below.

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 rust:slim as cargo-build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev openssl cmake -y

COPY . .

RUN cargo build --release

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ca-certificates libssl-dev openssl -y

WORKDIR /src/app

COPY .env .

COPY --from=cargo-build /usr/src/app/target/release/bario-beck .

ENV RUST_LOG=info

EXPOSE 8080

# Run the application
CMD ["./bario-beck"]
```

The building process breakes give the following message:

```
[1/2] STEP 6/6: RUN cargo build --release
    Updating crates.io index
Killed
Error: building at STEP "RUN cargo build --release": while running runtime: exit status 137
```

I read some similar issues and it was recommended to increase memory for the building process, so tried to increase memory and cpu config of my podman machine. From 1GB to 8GB of memory and from 1 CPU to 4, but I am still getting the same error. I also tried to build with docker but the error persist. I tried to build the code for the platform of my machine, `darwin/arm64`, with podman and docker and got the same error.

Here is my podman machine config:

```json
[
     {
          "ConfigPath": {
               "Path": "~/.config/containers/podman/machine/qemu/podman-machine-default.json"
          },
          "ConnectionInfo": {
               "PodmanSocket": {
                    "Path": "~/.local/share/containers/podman/machine/qemu/podman.sock"
               },
               "PodmanPipe": null
          },
          "Created": "2023-05-28T14:55:24.150251-03:00",
          "Image": {
               "IgnitionFilePath": {
                    "Path": "~/.config/containers/podman/machine/qemu/podman-machine-default.ign"
               },
               "ImageStream": "testing",
               "ImagePath": {
                    "Path": "~/.local/share/containers/podman/machine/qemu/podman-machine-default_fedora-coreos-38.20230514.2.0-qemu.aarch64.qcow2"
               }
          },
          "LastUp": "2023-05-28T15:56:43.403634-03:00",
          "Name": "podman-machine-default",
          "Resources": {
               "CPUs": 4,
               "DiskSize": 100,
               "Memory": 8192
          },
          "SSHConfig": {
               "IdentityPath": "~/.ssh/podman-machine-default",
               "Port": 51641,
               "RemoteUsername": "core"
          },
          "State": "running"
     }
]
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue with podman?

Comment: A [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=exit+status+137) suggests the container performing the build is running out of memory.

Comment: Yep, 137 is the OOM killer almost always.

Comment: That's kind of weird because I already double the amount of memory to podman to 16GB and still not building, on the other hand I was able to build the same code with it in a less powerful machine with only 4GB